# log4net database appender not inserting

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, log4net

My Database appender is not working and I can't figure out why, the connection is working and I've tested the appender's command text in sql management studio.

```
public class KennyLoggins
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public string Thread { get; set; }

    public string Level { get; set; }

    public string Logger { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public string Exception { get; set; }
}
```

I've setup tracing for log4net and it doesn't seem to be getting any errors.

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add
            name="textWriterTraceListener"
            type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
            initializeData="log4net_debug.txt" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

The log4net config:

```
<log4net>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="ADONetAppender" />
  </root>

  <appender name="ADONetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ADONetAppender">
    <bufferSize value="100" />
    <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
    <connectionString value="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDB;Integrated Security=True;" />
    <commandText value="INSERT INTO KennyLoggins ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />

    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_date"/>
      <dbType value="DateTime"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout"/>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@thread"/>
      <dbType value="String"/>
      <size value="255"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%thread"/>
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_level"/>
      <dbType value="String"/>
      <size value="50"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%level"/>
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@logger"/>
      <dbType value="String"/>
      <size value="255"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%logger"/>
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@message"/>
      <dbType value="String"/>
      <size value="4000"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%message"/>
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@exception"/>
      <dbType value="String"/>
      <size value="2000"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout"/>
    </parameter>
  </appender>

</log4net>
```

I'm using the same connection string that I'm using for Entity Framework with my ADONetAppender, could that be an issue?

Comment: Your buffer size is 100 which means log4net won't write log events until there are 100 of them, could that be it? Also, are you initialising log4net in your code?

Answer (score 2):

Set your buffer size to 1. If you have 100, the logger will wait till it has 100 messages before writing to your database.